# How to use Regex to find exact same sequence in php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regex to delete all characters after the exact sequence 'roast'. I tried the following.

```
echo preg_replace('/^[^roast]+/', '', "I ate a big roast and it was delicious.");
```

However, if there is one character from the list is found;not a sequence as a whole then regex is returning a match.In this case it is getting the 'a' of 'ate' as a match.

What I want: `" and it was delicious"`

What I am getting: `"ate a big roast and it was delicious."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex matches a sequence of characters other than r, o, a, s, or t, at the start of the string.

You want any string, followed by `roast`:

```
.+roast
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6gFES8/3

Comment: It is giving me "I ate a big roast". Which is exactly the opposite of what I am looking for.

Comment: I tried preg_replace('/(?<=roast).+/', '', "I ate a big roast and it was delicious.");

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  See updated answer.